# Why does GCC produce stack preservation instructions when they're not necessary?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc

I'm compiling the following simple demonstration function:

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Naturally this function would be inlined, but let's assume that it's dynamically linked or not inlined for some other reason. With optimization disabled, the compiler produces the expected code:

```
00000000 <add>:
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   8b 45 0c                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   6:   03 45 08                add    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   9:   5d                      pop    ebp
   a:   c3                      ret
```

Since there are no function calls inside this function, the instructions at 0, 1 and 9 seemingly have no purpose. Since optimization is disabled, this is acceptable.

However, when compiling while optimizing for size with `-Os -s`, the exact same code is produced. It seems rather wasteful to increase the size of the function by 66% with these options.

Why is the code not optimized to the following?

```
00000000 <add>:
   0:   8b 45 0c                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x8]
   3:   03 45 08                add    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x4]
   6:   c3                      ret
```

Does the compiler just not consider this worth optimizing or is it related to other details like function alignment?

Comment: there's also the possibility it's a security measure against certain stack smashing attacks.

Comment: @MarcB You're thinking of "stack canaries" which look rather different.  Frame pointers unfortunately don't help at all against a stack smash.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is done to preserve the ability of the debugger to step through your code.

If you really want to disable this try `-fomit-frame-pointer`.

Compiling your above code using `-Os -fomit-frame-pointer -S -masm=intel` gave this:

```
    .file   "frame.c"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .text
    .globl  _add
    .def    _add;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_add:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
    add eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
    ret
    .ident  "GCC: (rev0, Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.8.0"
```

Comment: +1 for `-fomit-frame-poionter`.  It does exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: N.B. `-fomit-frame-pointer` is on by default for x86-64, although possibly not for win64.

Answer (score 0):

The value of EBP is not known when the function enters.  Code could use `mov eax,dword ptr [esp+8]` and not bother with the `BP` register, but many debugging tools assume that each local variable is at a fixed offset relative to some register.  Even if a compiler could keep track of things that were pushed on the stack and adjust indexing offsets appropriately, debuggers would likely be unable to do so.